# How to make the text vertically centered bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have this output:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
<div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success pull-right">Send</button>
    <div id="total" class="pull-right vcenter">Total Amount: 0.00</div>
</div>
```

And here is the CSS:

```
.vcenter {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    float: none;
}
```

I want to make it like this:

[image]

What is the better way to do this?

Comment: try adding margin: 0; inside your vcenter class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Floats aren't the answer here. If you want `vertical-align` to work properly, both elements need to be `display: inline-block;`.

Answer (score 0):

set `line-height` equal to button height. Suppose height of button is 30px so css should be

```
.vcenter {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    float: none;
    line-height: 30px;
}
```

> line-height will set the height of text so equal height of text and button will give us vertically centered look

Answer (score 0):

you can use this

```
.vcenter {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: 30px;
}
```

by using float along with not solve your issue. so just leave that.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing
additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ it answers
the question would significantly improve its long-term
value.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation.

Answer (score 0):

This will solve the issue.

```
.align {
    line-height: 34px;
    margin: 0;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Html:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success pull-right">Send</button>
<p id="total" class="vcenter">Total Amount: 0.00</p>
```